ROS2 custom message pkg cannot find __init__.py when a python module is included
I created this package initially to have msgs to import into my main ROS package. That worked fine until I added
motorEnum.py in src/my_custom_package.

me
└── my_interfaces
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── my_interfaces
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── msg
    │   ├── Motor.msg
    │   ├── NearestObject.msg
    │   └── NearestObjects.msg
    ├── package.xml
    ├── setup.py
    └── src
        └── my_custom_pkg
            ├── __init__.py
            └── motorEnum.py

Now I can't get away from colcon (with or without --symlink-install) thinking this is mising:
__init__.py


CMake Error at
/opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_python/cmake/ament_python_install_package.cmake:66
(message):   ament_python_install_package() the Python package folder
'/home/me/my_interfaces_ws/my_interfaces/my_custom_pkg'   doesn't
contain an 'init.py' file

CMakeLists
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_custom_pkg)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/NearestObject.msg"
  "msg/NearestObjects.msg"
  "msg/Motor.msg"
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

message(STATUS "Python package directory: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/${PROJECT_NAME}")

# Install Python modules (from src directly)
install(
  DIRECTORY src/my_custom_pkg/
  DESTINATION lib/python3.8/site-packages
)

# If your package has Python code (e.g., MotorEnum.py), add the following:
ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()

setup.py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

package_name = 'my_custom_pkg'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=[package_name],  # This must match the directory inside src/
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
)

package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>my_custom_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="me@me.com">john</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>


  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

